# Why python doesn't accept my color i take from text file? Python Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm saving colors on text file and when i take them from there Python says color variable has quotation marks. I don't understand why, because when i print the variable there aren't quotation marks.

Here is some code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

with open('test.txt', 'r') as r:
    backround = r.readline()

l = Label(window, bg=backround)
l.pack()
```

Here is the error of the code executed above:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7wsQ.png)

And test.txt looks like this:

```
red
```

And if i print the same variable:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as r:
    backround = r.readline()

print(backround)
```

Output is only red, without any quotation marks.

Comment: The error does not seem to be because of quotation marks. Quotation marks are just shown to delimit the string. The error appears to be because of the new-line at the end of the string. You can remove that with `.strip()`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from the error picture that the issue has to do with new lines. That you think you send in **red** but what you actually send in is **red\n** which is not a color.

In the second example you should try with:

```
print("[" + backround + "]")
```

Then you can see if there is any strange charter between **red** and **]**

As khelwood wrote you could just write strip() and be rid of the newline.

```
l = Label(window, bg=backround.strip())
```